# Accessing Tiles attribute as a variable from Thymeleaf template?

Tags: spring, tiles, thymeleaf

I'm using *Spring* + *Thymeleaf* + *Tiles* combination.

I have a Tiles definition with a string attribute:

```
<definition name="myDef">
    <put-attribute name="myAttr" value="foo"/>
</definition>
```

In a Thymeleaf template I want to use `myAttr` in expressions:

```
<div th:if="${myAttr == 'foo'}">...</div>
```

**How whould I do it?**

All I found so far is how to renger Tiles attributes directly to the output (`<span tiles:string="myAttr" />`), but wasn't able to figure out how to insert its content into a context variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a workaround - render Tiles attribute to a `<span>`, replace Thymeleaf conditions with JavaScript conditions (I'm using Angular), read that `<span>` value into a JS variable and let the client to do the rest.